# Form element does not add label

Tags: html, accessibility

I want to have a label around my form element so that it is accessible, but writing it this way does not pass Firefox's WAVE accessible tool bar, can someone see what is wrong with it?

here is my code:

```
<div style="width:895px; max-width:100%; text-align:right;">
<label for="select document type">
Select: 
<select id="view" onchange="toggleElement(this)">
<option value="All">All</option>
<option value="Tenant">A</option>
<option value="Landlord">B</option>
</select>
</label>
</div>
```

Comment: LABEL tags do not wrap controls. They are supposed to be next to them.

Comment: so would it just wrap the words Select: ?

Comment: Correct. See: http://alistapart.com/article/prettyaccessibleforms

Comment: Sorry @diodeus, but wrapping `<label>` around controls is [perfectly valid](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/label). You then don't need the `for` attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is failing WAVE validation because you've misunderstood what the `for` attribute on `<label>` element is for.

If you wrap a `<label>` around the control, then the control is automatically associated with that label, and you should not put a `for` attribute. This method is outdated, and it should not be used, but it still can be done.

If you do NOT wrap the control within the `<label>` then the `for` attribute should be the `id` of the control that it is associated with.

For instance...

```
<label>
  Select: 
  <select id="view">
    ...
  </select>
</label>
```

OR...

```
<label for="view">
  Select: 
</label>
<select id="view">
  ...
</select>
```

You appear to be using `for` as if it will become a tooltip message (if this is what you meant, then use a `title` attribute instead). Please note, that the `title` attribute is sometimes read instead of the `<label>`, so it can cause confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you would have to wrap your label around your element to make it accessible.
But you can do either way: wrapping around, or have a `for=""` matching the id of your element (your `select`).

So if you wrap around, you don't need the `for=`, so something like this should work:

```
<div style="width:895px; max-width:100%; text-align:right;">
    <label>
        Select: 
        <select id="view" onchange="toggleElement(this)">
            <option value="All">All</option>
            <option value="Tenant">A</option>
            <option value="Landlord">B</option>
        </select>
    </label>
</div>
```

But you could also use a correct `for` instead of wrapping. The `for` must match the `id` in that case:

```
<div style="width:895px; max-width:100%; text-align:right;">
    <label for="view">
        Select: 
    </label>
    <select id="view" onchange="toggleElement(this)">
        <option value="All">All</option>
        <option value="Tenant">A</option>
        <option value="Landlord">B</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Edit: you can see what was wrong by validating your html:
http://validator.nu/

> Error: Bad value select document type for attribute for on element label:
>   An ID must not contain whitespace.
>
> `:right;">↩<label for="select document type">↩Selec`
>
> Error: Any select descendant of a label element with a for attribute
>   must have an ID value that matches that for attribute.
>
> `↩Select: ↩<select id="view" onchange="toggleElement(this)">↩<opti`
>
> Error: The for attribute of the label element must refer to a form
>   control.
>
> `:right;">↩<label for="select document type">↩Selec`

The 3 errors mentioned above are all because of the bad `for` attribute.